# How to delete InsideView from sugarcrm?

Tags: sugarcrm

I tried to delete InsideView from sugarcrm, but I do not know where to find the templete which includes them, It seems that InsideView was created by javascript.

could any one tell me how to delete InsideView from sugarcrm?

Comment: Try to disable Modules in Connectors. Please check http://stackoverflow.com/a/42367292/6056191

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can disable the InsideView connector from the Admin area which will hide it. Go to Admin->Connectors->Enable Connectors. Then select the InsideView tab and drag over all modules from Enabled to Disabled.