# How to remove or hide InsideView panel from Lead detail view in SugarCRM 6.5?

Tags: sugarcrm

In Lead detail view i can see community ads in "InsideView" panel [Community Forum](http://community.insideview.com). I am currently on 6.5 community edition.

Is this possible to hide or remove?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

I found this solution

Just open below page:

`Admin » Connector Settings » Enable Connectors`

And move all modules to Disabled panel and Save.

Comment: You're right this is the way to go from within the UI. The solution I suggested is for an installable package.

Answer (score 1):

Place this in a post_install routine:

```
require_once('include/connectors/utils/ConnectorUtils.php');
require_once('include/connectors/sources/SourceFactory.php');

ConnectorUtils::cleanMetaDataFile('Leads');

write_array_to_file('modules_sources', array(), CONNECTOR_DISPLAY_CONFIG_FILE);
write_array_to_file('searchdefs', array(), 'custom/modules/Connectors/metadata/searchdefs.php');

$s = SourceFactory::getSource('ext_rest_insideview');
$s->saveMappingHook(array());
```